# Scala: finding the difference between 2 lists

Tags: scala

Let's say I have two lists:

```
var l1 = List(1,0,0) and var l2 = List(0,0,1)
```

Now, I am trying to find the difference between these 2 lists, using only `map`, `reduce` and `filter` functions. Also, when I say difference, I mean that I want to compare the same spots in the list. For example `l1(0)` is compared to `l2(0)`, `l1(1)` compared to `l2(1)`, etc. After all have been compared, I return a number that represents the number of different elements between the two lists. How will I do that?

Comment: Why the strange restriction to `map`, `reduce` and `filter`? Why not `zip`?

Comment: Why can’t you do like this? Set(l1) diff Set(l2)?

Comment: @RamanMishra Try it on `val l1 = List(0,0,0,0,0)` and `val l2 = List(1,1,1,1,1)`. How many elements will the sets have? How will you get a 5 out of it?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I know what it will give ok.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrey suggested short and easy.

```
l1.zip(l2).count(t2 => t2._1 != t2._2)
```

Comment: `t2` makes the whole expression look asymmetric, because `1` appears a different number of times than `2`. I'd prefer to name the argument just `t` ;)

Comment: yes you are right, but i have some 'bad' habit to define tuple2 as t2, tuple3 as t3... for easy reading.

Comment: What @Andrey said, or even  `{ case (a, b) => a != b }`. Unfortunately `(l1, l2).zipped.count(_ != _)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If `length` is allowed:

```
(0 until l1.length).filter { i => l1(i) != l2(i) }.length
```

If not (to be *really* strict, replace `.length` with `.map(_ => 1).reduce(_ + _)`):

```
(0 until l1.length).map { i => if (l1(i) == l2(i)) 0 else 1 }
                   .reduce(_ + _)
```

The latter will fail on empty lists. You could instead do, if you allow `reduceOption`:

```
(0 until l1.length).map { i => if (l1(i) == l2(i)) 0 else 1 }
                   .reduceOption(_ + _).getOrElse(0)
```

In either case, you probably want to use `Vector` instead of `List` since `List` indexing is slow. And, of course, `zip` is much more idiomatic than indexing, and will even be fast on `List`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Hence the third code code sample (I know, I wasn't explicit that you'd need to use reduceOption both places). I'm pretty sure it's impossible to correctly handle empty lists without `reduceOption`, recursion, folds, or some other feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
val elem= l1.zip(l2).filter(_.1 != _.2).length
```

It will serve the purpose.